# how to add namespaces in in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

How do i add namespaces to the visual studio, I mean on the java word is common that the (if you have provided the reference to the right library) you can add the import to the java "namespace". (See picture).

[image: Adding a namespace in netbeans (Java)]

Is there some similar feature in C# ? I mean, I find it very hard to fish the right namespaces, because as a java programer the IDE assists me...

As you can see in the given example Netbeans even let me choose which "namespace" is to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

- Do it with your mouse like in the picture.
- Or press `CTRL + .` or `SHIFT + ALT + F10` (they do the same)
- Or use reSharper and just press `ALT + ENTER`

Comment: You can also hit `CTRL + .`, and get the same result as with SHIFT + ALT + F10.

Comment: nice, that's a lot more convenient.

Comment: Indeed. I feel like I am a circus artist sometimes when I'm trying to tackle some key combinations :)

Answer (score 1):

Click on the piece of code and press

```
SHIFT + ALT + F10
```

If you use ReSharper

```
ALT + Enter
```

and visual studio will provide you with some options

Answer (score 0):

See [Pre-defined Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are looking for visual studio shortcuts.

Click on the **type** and press

> SHIFT + ALT + F10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Add Using" intellisense in visual studio as given in the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3shw4wa2.aspx